# All .lnk associated with an explorer - mistake

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-association

I wanted to associate folder shortcuts to my new File Explorer *Total Commander* (or TCM). So I changed them in

> Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations

But what I did change was .lnk extension to that *every* single link on my computer is now associated with TCM. This is what it looks like https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4t1z8sue4avq8w/Screenshot%202014-10-04%2022.08.17.png?dl=0 so even the taskbar is associated with TCM (that blue/white icon is TCM). I then uninstalled TCM.

How do I "undo" what I have messed up?

Comment: I have also tried this solution http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

Comment: Then I tried this solution that should remove file associations for files and links http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-dissociate-file-types-in-windows-7-and-vista

Comment: This is still not fixed, since than I have tried http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html and http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-dissociate-file-types-in-windows-7-and-vista

Answer (score 1):

This solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e8631c28-4ce5-43cc-8865-b75fa2255b57/desktop-and-start-program-icon-lnk-file-associations?forum=itprovistadesktopui has popped up a few times during my research. Of course, depending on whether it has been set up, you may have the more crude alternative - running a System Restore.

(Speaking of SR, you may anyway want to set up a restore point before running anything that touches the Registry...)

Comment: So now the programs look fine in the taskbar. But [navigating in folders is still not working](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i58a5d0qbv4b0lt/Screenshot%202014-10-05%2011.11.57.png?dl=0)

Comment: I used a restore point (to a point *before* I installed TCM)). It did not work. What can I do?

Comment: Sorry, I've ran out of ideas. Hope you will get it fixed somehow.

Comment: I logged in to the guest user. Everything is fine here.